# How to color the utility icons in lightning datatable in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds, button, lightning-buttonicon

I have the below data table where I have two icons. I want to change the color to blue instead of grey. The variant property is not helpful. How do I do that?

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="myTable">
            <lightning-datatable 
                    key-field="id"
                    data={filesList}
                    columns={columns}
                    hide-checkbox-column="true"
                    onrowaction={handleRowActions}
                    >
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';


const columns = [
    { label: 'Filename', fieldName: 'label', hideDefaultActions: "true" },
    { label: 'Type', fieldName: 'type', hideDefaultActions: "true" },
    { label: 'Size', fieldName: 'size', hideDefaultActions: "true" },
    {
        label: 'Preview',
        type: 'button-icon',
        typeAttributes:
        {
            iconName: 'utility:preview',
            name: 'Preview',
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Download',
        type: 'button-icon',
        typeAttributes:
        {
            iconName: 'utility:download',
            name: 'Download',
        }
    }

];
export default class sampleComponent extends LightningElement {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 problems that prevent us from using "Styling Hooks" to achieve custom styling.

1. Per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button-icon/documentation), `--sds-c-button-text-color` is not available for use in any of the `lightning-button-icon` variants.
2. Styling hooks don't seem to apply to base components nested inside `lightning-datatable` unless we apply them to the `:host` selector, which isn't recommended. Your CSS selector needs to be as selective as possible. Also, using the host selector would apply the style every element instead of just the ones we want (in this example, the styling must be limited to the buttons in one or two columns).

So here is a workaround to style `lightning-button-icon` inside the `lightning-datatable`.

First, create a CSS file, let's say `datatablestyles.css`, and define a custom class with the styling you want. In this case, we want to change the icon color, so we can go with either the `fill` property or use an LWC Design Token.

```css
.myCustomDatatableIconColor{
    fill: blue;
    // alternately, you can use LWC Design Tokens
    // --lwc-colorTextIconDefault: blue;
}
```

Next, upload this file as a static resource with the same name, and import it in your LWC Component.

```js
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import datatablestyles from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/datatablestyles';

...

connectedCallback(){
    loadStyle(this, datatable);
}
```

Finally, you need to update your column definition to use the custom CSS class your created, via the `iconClass` typeAttribute

```js
{
    label: 'Preview',
    type: 'button-icon',
    typeAttributes:
    {
        iconName: 'utility:preview',
        name: 'Preview',
        iconClass: 'myCustomDatatableIconColor'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [Create a Custom Data Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types) to apply whatever styling you want; that is necessary AFAIK as other approaches are deliberately blocked. That approach also allows multiple buttons to be grouped in one table column.

(I've used the `variant` property to have blue icons and that is nice and simple. Can you add to your question to explain why "The variant property is not helpful"? )

Answer (score 3):

As you have found, the `button-icon` type, which creates a `lightning-button-icon`, only supports variant which provides for just a few select colours, as [documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button-icon/documentation). If you need to be able to explicitly define the button colour using CSS colour options then you need to create a specialized `lighting-datatable` that uses a custom data type for this column, and create your own equivalent to the `lightning-button`.

The former is done, as @Keith C said, using the [documented approach](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types).

The latter is done by consulting the SLDS [Component Blueprint for button icon](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/button-icons/), then modifying it to allow setting of the icon's colour using a property passed to the custom type from the datatable.

Colouring an SVG foreground/outline/background is the trick here, and you can deal with that using SVG CSS properties `fill` or `stroke` for example. This is done by setting the `style` attribute on the SVG element appropriately in the custom column's HTML, based on setting this up as needed as part of the column data. See the icon button blue print to see how the HTML includes an SVG element, on which you do this "override", that "wraps" the content loaded from the standard SVG file.

Answer (score 0):

Other option besides using custom type is to put CSS in StaticResource. It ignores Shadow DOM and you can style lighting-button-icon.

But since this styles will be global for the whole Salesforce it's best to prefix selectors with your component name.